# Hibernate performance after database restore, in Grails

Tags: performance, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to Hibernate, so i don't know where to look for an answer.

I have a system that runs some calculations and every day it does a database backup, so my system is backed up daily.

This works very fast but when i restore one of those daily backups, (in Mysql or in H2DB) then the performance drops significantly.

Hibernate has a Context, and flushing and stuff ...

Can someone explain what should i do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I restore from MySQL backups frequently and do not notice a slow-down in Grails performance.  I doubt there is anything you need to do on the Grails/Hibernate end of things... unless you are leaving Grails running and restoring the DB underneath it, which is something I have never tried.  In that case, you may want to try cleaning up the hibernate session a la [this post](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Garbage-collection-td1585235.html):

```
def propertyInstanceMap = org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DomainClassGrailsPlugin.PROPERTY_INSTANCE_MAP

private void cleanUpGorm() {
    def session = sessionFactory.currentSession
    session.flush()
    session.clear()
    propertyInstanceMap.get().clear()
}
```

Comment: I tried this many times, but i didnt solve my performance issues.